# Handle CDATA in JAXB

Tags: java

I need to parse a xml file (I do parse using JAXB) , but i want to take some part of the Xml file value into a string. After i surfed in net, it can be possible by using CDATA. The follwing link talks about CDATA. But i do have a doubt in the code. Where and how should i  specify which of my elements i want to be handled as CDATA.

http://jaxb.java.net/faq/JaxbCDATASample.java

My XML look like the following.

```
<root>
    <Service>CDATASERVICE</Service>
    <Child>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>Servicename</name>
                        <value>service1</value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>item1</name>
                        <value>36</value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Cdata</name>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member>
                                    <name>services</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <array>
                                            <data>
                                                <value>ABCD</value>
                                            </data>
                                        </array>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>item2</name>
                        <value>
                            <int>10</int>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </Child>
</root>
```

I want to take the following part as a string from the above XML file, how can i get that.

```
                 <name>Cdata</name>
                            <value>
                                <struct>
                                    <member>
                                        <name>services</name>
                                        <value>
                                            <array>
                                                <data>
                                                    <value>ABCD</value>
                                                </data>
                                            </array>
                                        </value>
                                    </member>
                                </struct>
                            </value>
```

Comment: This is how you wrap CDATA: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `@XmlAnyElement` with a `DomHandler` specified for this use case.

**MemberHandler**

An `@XmlAnyElement` annotation allows you to keep portions of an XML document as XML.  By default this is kept as DOM nodes.  By implementing a `DomHandler` you can leverage an alternate representation such as a `String`.

```
package forum12512299;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.DomHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class MemberHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {

    private static final String MEMBER_START_TAG = "<member>";
    private static final String MEMBER_END_TAG = "</member>";

    private StringWriter xmlWriter;

    public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        xmlWriter = new StringWriter();
        return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
    }

    public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
        String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(MEMBER_START_TAG) + MEMBER_START_TAG.length();
        int endIndex = xml.indexOf(MEMBER_END_TAG);
        return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = MEMBER_START_TAG + n.trim() + MEMBER_END_TAG;
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Struct**

Below is an example of how the `DomHandler` is referenced from an `@XmlAnyElement` mapping.

```
package forum12512299;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Struct {

    private List<String> members;

    @XmlAnyElement(MemberHandler.class)
    public List<String> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<String> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

Below I've simplified your XML document down to the interesting part:

```xml
<struct>
    <member>
        <name>item1</name>
        <value>36</value>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Cdata</name>
        <value>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>services</name>
                    <value>
                        <array>
                            <data>
                                <value>ABCD</value>
                            </data>
                        </array>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </value>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>item2</name>
        <value>
            <int>10</int>
        </value>
    </member>
</struct>
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12512299;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Struct.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12512299/input.xml");
        Struct struct = (Struct) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        for(String string : struct.getMembers()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<name>item1</name><value>36</value>

<name>Cdata</name><value><struct><member><name>services</name><value><array><data><value>ABCD</value>
                            </data>
                        </array>
                    </value>

<name>item2</name><value><int>10</int>
        </value>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reference to CDATA in the title of your question is misleading. A CDATA section in XML is a part of the XML file written like this:

```
<![CDATA[ … ]]>
```

The content of that section is not parsed as XML, but instead treated as raw character text. Therefore it is an alternative to writing `&lt;` for every `<` in that part.

CDATA isn't part of the XML infoset. Most Applications will not, cannot and should not care whether input text is written as a CDATA section, as “normal” text or as a mixture of these two. Only at the very low level of an actual serialized file representation, where you also deal with stuff like whitespace, indentation, chracter encoding and so on, does CDATA matter. That's the example you referred to: apparently there is a way to tell JAXB that a given string should be rendered as a CDATA section or as “normal” XML with character references.

For your application, this appears to be of little use. In order to make use of CDATA, your input XML would *already* have to contain the CDATA markup. As it does not (according to our example), the parser has no choice but to treat it as well-formed XML. The [answer by Blaise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12513650) already pointed out how you might still be able to represent that subtree “as is” inside your data structures, either as a DOM node or as an XML String.

Comment: Explaining to someone, who needs help in regards to CDATA, to basically not have to care (while he or she obviously has to), is imo not helpful - which is why I downvoted this reply.

Comment: @Igor: I appreciate the explanation for the downvote. I believe this question here is suffering from the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): it is asking about CDATA as a means for preserving arbitrary content of a given element, but the accepted answer explains how to do that without CDATA. My answer augments that by explaining why CDATA is not suitable unless you control the XML you're given. The question of “how do I just get the content of a given element as a string exactly as it was in the input file” has the answer “you don't”, and has nothing to do with CDATA.